# static reference to an Interface

Tags: java, android

I am passing some of my custom objects from activity to `Fragment` through new instance. I faced a problem sending one of my interface reference through new instance and accessing it through `getArguments()`.

I have implemented the interface class with `Serializable` and it ended up with a crash saying `serializable I.O. Exception` since I have passed `Map<K,V>` as params in my interface methods.

And so as a workaround, I have assigned the interface reference as local `private static` arg. And nullified the arg when the fragment is not visible to the user in `setUserVisibleHint(boolean)` and it is working perfectly. I want to know if the implementation is correct.

Below is my code:

```
private static ISelectedAnswer iSelectedAns;

public static QuestionFragment newInstance(QuizQuestions quizQuestions, int position,  ISelectedAnswer iSelectedAnswer) {
    QuestionFragment fragmentFirst = new QuestionFragment();
    Bundle bundle = new Bundle();

    iSelectedAns = iSelectedAnswer;

    String question = quizQuestions.getQuestion();
    bundle.putString(Constants.QUESTION, question);
    bundle.putInt(Constants.PAGE_POSITION, position);
    fragmentFirst.setArguments(bundle);
    return fragmentFirst;
}
```

And the interface declaration is.

```
public interface ISelectedAnswer extends Serializable {
    /**
     * Will store the page position and the selected answers through the Map Interface.
     *
     * @param selectedAnswer - selected answer id.
     * @param quizData
     */
    void selectedChoice(HashMap<Integer, Object> selectedAnswer, HashMap<Integer, List<Integer>>
            quizData);

    /**
     * Will cancel the countdown timer.
     *
     * @param isCancel
     */
    void cancelTimer(boolean isCancel);
}
```

Comment: You need to pass it as bundle

Comment: `I want to know if the implementation is correct.` if it works, It's correct just leave it alone :p

Comment: @SamzSakerz Using static variables in general does not work in Android (if you test long enough).

Comment: @Henry I never go all out on `static` vars where I don't need them so I wouldnt know ;o

Comment: @SamzSakerz previously I have passed the reference through bundle and that caused crash...

Comment: I'm not sure what the crash would be without the stacktrace

Answer (score 0):

Setting your callback variable as static is not a good method to solve fragment-activity communication.

> To allow a Fragment to communicate up to its Activity, you can define
>   an interface in the Fragment class and implement it within the
>   Activity. The Fragment captures the interface implementation during
>   its onAttach() lifecycle method and can then call the Interface
>   methods in order to communicate with the Activity.

Here is an example of Fragment to Activity communication:

Headlines Fragment

```
public class HeadlinesFragment extends ListFragment {
    OnHeadlineSelectedListener mCallback;

    public void setOnHeadlineSelectedListener(Activity activity) {
        mCallback = activity;
    }

    // Container Activity must implement this interface
    public interface OnHeadlineSelectedListener {
        public void onArticleSelected(int position);
    }

    // ...
}
```

MainActivity

```
public static class MainActivity extends Activity
        implements HeadlinesFragment.OnHeadlineSelectedListener{
    // ...

    @Override
    public void onAttachFragment(Fragment fragment) {
        if (fragment instanceof HeadlinesFragment) {
            HeadlinesFragment headlinesFragment = (HeadlinesFragment) fragment;
            headlinesFragment.setOnHeadlineSelectedListener(this);
        }
    }
}
```

You can get more information from [here](https://developer.android.com/training/basics/fragments/communicating)

I've also created an example [project](https://github.com/theapache64/fragment_communication) on github about this. You can clone/download to run the code to see the working.

Comment: - thanks for your solution. I think this is better than what I have implemented (static reference). It's working.

Comment: You're welcome. You may mark this answer as correct If it helped you. @Ram

Answer (score 0):

I would like to recommend to have a class for passing it as between activity and fragments. Then pass the class as a `Bundle` in your `Fragment`. If the work-around works in your case, then it is fine. However, a better implementation that I think, should be like the following.

Get a class having the Quiz Data.

```
public Class QuizData {
    public HashMap<Integer, Object> selectedAnswer; 
    public HashMap<Integer, List<Integer>> quizData;
}
```

When you are implementing the interface in your `Activity`, you need to initiate the class and put the values in it and then pass it to the other fragment where this is necessary.

You can have an interface in your calling `Activity` as well which can be declared as `public`. You can always access the public interface declared and implemented in your `Activity` from the `Fragment`.